# Nodejs: wait for mongodb connection to be made, before creating http server

Tags: node.js, mongodb

in my `app.js`, I create a mongodb connection when app starts.

```
mongoose.connect(config.db, {});

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', function () {
    log.error("Failed to connect to database");
    process.exit(1);
});
db.once('open', function () {
    log.info("Connected to database");
});
```

The `app.js` is used from `bin/www.js` (with `require('./../app')`), in which the http server is created.

Currently, if db connection is unsuccessful, app terminates, but http server got created before terminating, since db creation failure is reported asynchronously.

I need to block http server creation until db connection is successful, but I need to keep the server creation code in `bin/www.js` itself, without moving it to db connection successful callback in `app.js`.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Move your web server listeners inside `db.once('open'....`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can launch your server only when the connection is done:

```
db.once('open', function () {
   log.info('Connected to database');
   launchMyServer()
});
```

or if you want to use it in another file :

```
module.exports = function initConnection(callback) {
  mongoose.connect(config.db, {});
  var db = mongoose.connection;
  db.on('error', function (err) {
    log.error('Failed to connect to database');
    process.exit(1);
  });

  db.once('open', function () {
    log.info("Connected to database");
    callback();
  });
};
```

And from your `www.js` file:

```
const initConnection = require('./../app')

initConnection(function () {
  launchMyServer()
})
```

Comment: As I have mentioned, server creation is done in `bin/www.js`, and `app.js` is included from it, where the db connection is made. I would like to keep it that way.

Comment: You can use `module.exports = ` to export the function